# I can't render volumetric lights in Eevee with an orthographic camera

Tags: rendering, camera, volumetrics, eevee-render-engine, orthographic

So this is the problem I'm having, when I render volumetric lights in Eevee, they don't show up with an orthographic Camera, but they do when using a perspective camera. Why is that? is there a way to render them on orthographic?

To clarify I'm using 1fc75dbbceea version (latest as of today 19-dec), and they do show on the viewport but not in the final render. And the Volumetric option is checked on the Render tab.

[image: Render result of default spotlight through a default cube with default Principled Volume Shader, with a camera in perspective mode]

*Render result of default spotlight through a default cube with default Principled Volume Shader, with a camera in perspective mode*

[image: Same but with a camera in orthographic mode]

*Same but with a camera in orthographic mode*

[image: Startup file then Volumetrics checked]

*Startup file then Volumetrics checked*

Comment: You can post some screenshot?!

Comment: This looks like it could be a bug.. I am up against the exact same issue.. https://developer.blender.org/T57617

Comment: Appears it is still that way (need to use perspective view for volumetric lighting to show up in EEVEE editor window). May be in the design. Not sure.